# Help me with remote method of jquery validation plugin

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Can anyone help me with jquery remote: validation method. I mean I got how to use it in the jquery part. Just can anyone tell me the server side part. I am using PHP and codeigniter to do it. Just consider an example below:

```
$("#myform").validate({ 
    rules: { 
        email: { 
            required: true, 
            email: true, 
            remote: "validate/check" 
        } 
    } 
});
```

So now can anyone tell me what's the code for check function in validate controller?

Comment: why not $this->form_validation->set_rules(blablablabla) ?

Comment: @Gerep: I want to use jquery for validation.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to understand that the remote file must me a php file say, `test.php`.

You may create one file which returns "true" for succes and "false" for error.

You can see more details [here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

The plugin itself validates input email format. Also, you can see a simple email validation using php here;

http://www.totallyphp.co.uk/code/validate_an_email_address_using_regular_expressions.htm

http://www.builderau.com.au/program/php/soa/Simplify-e-mail-validation-routines-with-PHP/0,339028448,339221002,00.htm

Answer (score 0):

The point is that, you should use `echo json_encode(TRUE/FALSE);` to return the validation result to jquery

Controller Example:

```
//---------------------------------
// EMAIL EXISTS (true or false)
//---------------------------------
private function email_exists($email)
{
  $this->db->where('email', $email);
  $query = $this->db->get('users');
  if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ){ return TRUE; } else { return FALSE; }
}

//---------------------------------
// AJAX REQUEST, IF EMAIL EXISTS
//---------------------------------
function register_email_exists()
{
  if (array_key_exists('email',$_POST)) {
    if ( $this->email_exists($this->input->post('email')) == TRUE ) {
      echo json_encode(FALSE);
    } else {
      echo json_encode(TRUE);
    }
  }
}
```

This tutorial would help you to understand  http://www.joshuawinn.com/check-if-email-username-exists-with-codeigniter-and-jquery-validation/