# Remote method using jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help me with remote method of jquery validation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562762/help-me-with-remote-method-of-jquery-validation-plugin)

Can anyone help me with jquery remote: validation method. I mean I got how to use it in the jquery part. Just can anyone tell me the server side part. I am using PHP and codeigniter to do it. Just consider an example below:

```
$("#myform").validate({ 
    rules: { 
        email: { 
            required: true, 
            email: true, 
            remote: "validate/check" 
        } 
    } 
});
```

So now can anyone tell me what's the code for check function in validate controller?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: I have asked same question as no one responded to the earlier one...

Comment: that's not a reason for posting duplicates. If nobody answered your question you must consider the fact that your question might not be clear enough. Or that simply people haven't seen it yet. In both cases you should never post duplicates. So go ahead and delete this dupe before it gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

1. remote file must be `somefile.php`
2. the file may return "true" for
   success and "false" for error

You can see more details at http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

The plugin itself validates input email format. Also, you can see a simple email validation using php here;

http://www.totallyphp.co.uk/code/validate_an_email_address_using_regular_expressions.htm

http://www.builderau.com.au/program/php/soa/Simplify-e-mail-validation-routines-with-PHP/0,339028448,339221002,00.htm